# How to fix error json for json_encode

Tags: json

I have a json data like this :

```
$a = '[{"a":"1","b":"2","c":}]';
```

When to use `json_decode($a);` it returns an array.  So what should I to to return a value like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 
        )
)
```

Thanks !

Comment: What is the value for key **`c`** in `$a = '[{"a":"1","b":"2","c":}]';`

Comment: your current json is not valid [check] (http://jsonlint.com/). try to pass **"c":""** instead of only "c":

Comment: This is a sample data, when I have the big data from api, there are many records and if one of them has invalid value, when I use json_decode it will return empty array. So how to correct this data before use json_decode, such as add a null value for this